# How to sort listOfItem based on condition in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

This is my given code

```
var type1 listOf<Type> = 0 size;
var type2 listOf<Type> = {"Ait 45","Ait 46"}
var type3 listOf<Type> = {"Ait 47"}
var type4 listOf<Type> = 0
var type5 listOf<Type> = {"Ait 58","Ait 59"}
```

Using below code i am sorting it

```
val data = ArrayList<Product>()
        data.add(Product(it=1,type1))
        data.add(Product(it=2,type2))
        data.add(Product(it=3,type3))
        data.add(Product(it=4,type3))
        data.add(Product(it=5,type4))

data.sortedBy { it.type.get(0).value}
```

i am trying to sort based on type value but i am getting ArrayIndexoutBound exception because type1  and type4 having   empty or null so i want to  sort if such type of item should come at last  based on inserted order please help me how to apply condition to check if type  is empty or null i dont want sort those item simply i can keep at end of list .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `List<E>.get(index: Int): E` which [returns the element at the specified index in the list](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/get.html).
By the way, as this is an operator fun you could as well use the shorthand syntax `it.type[0].value`, which is the exact same.

However, this won't fix your problem.
If you're unsure that an element exists at the specified index, you should rather use a function that can cope with this, such as `List<T>.getOrNull(index: Int): T?`, which [returns an element at the given index or null if the index is out of bounds of this list](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-null.html).

Thus, you might end up with something along the lines of:

```kotlin
data.sortedBy { it.type.getOrNull(0)?.value}
```

---

Note that `sortedBy` [returns a list of all elements sorted according to **natural sort order** of the value returned by specified selector function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html).

If you want a custom sort order, you might want to take a look at [sortedWith](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html) instead, which allows to define a custom `Comparator`.

Comment: Thanks for update let me try your solution .